# React web app fetch data from parquet file on S3

Tags: reactjs, typescript, parquet

I’m trying to build a web application that reads data from parquet files stored on AWS S3 buckets.

Anyone has an updated solution to read/process the parquet files on the React side?
Or should a middleware be used to process the parquet file before returning it to the client (React app)?

(Seems like the packages available on npm are old/no longer maintained)